# Setting dual monitor with different resolutions using ati open source driver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, multi-monitor, radeon

I have **two** Monitors and am using Arch Linux, setup like this:

- 1280x1024 (primary)
- 1680x1050 (secondary)
- ATI RADEON X1300
- Open source ATI driver

On the boot screen, my primary monitor (17") has the correct resolution; my second CLONES the first and has the same resolution (1280x1024).

I have to run `xrandr` TWICE after starting X to get correct resolution.

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1280x1024 --output DVI-1 --mode 1680x1050 --left-of DVI-0
```

I tried to make this permanent by adding the `xrandr` command to `.xinitrc`, but it didn't work. Now, if I want to get the correct resolution on both monitors, after starting X, I run `xrandr` TWICE.

I didn't define anything in `xorg.conf` (nor do I know how :) ). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please write, how exactly did you put `xrandr` command in your `.xinitrc`. I have a similar setup and it works this way.

Comment: If you have to run it twice, and .xinitrc does not work, maybe try later. In my case, I use KDE, and I have option to setup scripts to be run after login, so my screens are setup after I successfully login.

Comment: Are you sure that your display manager even executes `~/.xinitrc`? If it's in there and it is executed, it should work. Otherwise, your DM probably has an equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Putting `xrandr` commands in `.xinitrc` is not a proper way to store permanent settings. You should use `xorg.conf` instead.

So start from removing the xrandr lines from your `.xinitrc`, and then create (or edit) an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. It should look exactly like this (no more content is needed unless you want to configure keyboard, mouse or similar devices):

```
Section "Monitor"
     Identifier "First monitor"
     Option     "PreferredMode"   "1280x1024"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
     Identifier "Second monitor"
     Option     "PreferredMode"   "1680x1050"
     Option     "LeftOf"          "First monitor"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Radeon X1300"
    Driver      "radeon"
    Option      "Monitor-DVI-0"   "First monitor"
    Option      "Monitor-DVI-1"   "Second monitor"
EndSection
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after so many attemps! To add to the answer, to find out your video card driver run this in terminal: `sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration`. I am using awesome wm on crunchbang waldorf.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a couple times as well.

For some reason, my screens have a nasty habit of changing their "name" sometimes, rendering whatever piece of code I set out with `xrandr` useless.

First double check that the monitors are correctly identified:

```
xmax@max-desktop:~> xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3360 x 1050, maximum 3360 x 1050
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1400x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       59.9  
   1360x1024      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       60.0  
   1152x864       59.9     75.0  
   1280x768       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT2 connected 1680x1050+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1400x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       59.9  
   1360x1024      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       60.0  
   1152x864       59.9     75.0  
   1280x768       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9
```

If the names are right, then I suspect that the system is NOT reading `~/.xinitrc` at boot or you've entered the command incorrectly.